# How to maintain a single session for a single browser using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session, session-state

I'm only getting started with making web applications in ASP.NET and I'm toying with the Global Application CLass, and what I noticed is, the Session_Start method in it is called for each unique browser window. That is, when if I open the webpage in two different Internet Explorer windows, it executes twice.

This isn't ideal right? I mean, if I were to develop a real time application, I wouldn't want this to happen right? Like, when I do the same thing with Gmail.com - if I sign into one Internet Explorer window, and open Gmail on another one, I stay signed in. This is because of sessions right?

In either case, is there any way to achieve what I just said using sessions?

Comment: Sounds strange to me. I have not seen this before - the two instances of IE would normally be associated with one session.

Comment: @Oded that's what happens in PHP when you use $_SESSION. I don't know why this is happening and if this is how it should be happening.

Comment: It shouldn't, as far as I know. It would if you use _different_ browsers or close all instances of one and reopen, but not if both instances are alive (barring session timeouts - the default is 20 minutes).

Comment: Depends on IE version. In pre IE8 versions of IE, starting a new IE window from for instance a destop shortcut would also start a new session. The new window would not share cookies with pre-existing IE windows. This was changed form IE8 and forward. Now you must explicitly start a new session from File menu.

Comment: @user1429080 that's interesting. I'll try that when I have access to my computer again.

Comment: @GrowingMan To elaborate a bit: In IE7 and earlier, the behaviour differed depending on how you started the new window. If from a desktop shortcut - the new window got a new session. Whereas if you press Ctrl-N in an existing window, the new window is attached to the same session. In IE8 and newer, starting a new window from shortcut associates the new window with an existing session.